# binomial theorem/ combinatorics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Professor McBrain has taught the same course for the last 12 years and tells 3
jokes each year. He has never told the same set of three jokes twice (the order of
the jokes is unimportant). How many jokes must he know?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have done and where you are stuck. Hint: can you answer the question for one joke? For two?

Comment: $ \binom{n}{3} \geq 12$ ... $n \geq ? $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He knows at least six jokes because

${6}\choose{3}$>12.

This assumes that he never tells the same joke twice in a given year.